# How to deal with this : selected processor does not support `qadd16 r1,r1,r0'

Tags: c, assembly, android-ndk, arm, abi

I am developing android application and in that i am working on NDK. while compiling the files i got the error of **selected processor does not support `qadd16 r1,r1,r0'**. can anyone explain me why and where this error comes and how to deal with this error? Here is my code snippet of [basic_op.h](http://pastie.org/4271537) file

```
static inline Word32 L_add(register Word32 ra, register Word32 rb)
{
  Word32 out;

  __asm__("qadd %0, %1, %2"
          : "=r"(out)
          : "r"(ra), "r"(rb));

  return (out);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you compiling just for ARM?

Comment: Actually i want to create one library(.so) file which will be loaded in my application.

Comment: The processor you're targetting does not have a "qaddr" instruction. Why are you doing this in assembly instead of C or Java, by the way?

Comment: ohh okay so which processor i should use to run this?

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan thanks i got your answer

Comment: @juned: So is that ARM or not? `qadd` is only supported in ARM(v6+).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because `QADD` instruction is not supported on your target architecture (http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0211h/Chddhfig.html). To compile this code you need to enable arm-v7 support in NDK.

Add the line

```
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
```

to your Application.mk and this code will compile perfectly:

```
static inline unsigned int L_add(register unsigned int ra, register unsigned int rb)
{
  unsigned int out;

  __asm__("qadd %0, %1, %2"
          : "=r"(out)
          : "r"(ra), "r"(rb));

  return (out);
}
```

**P.S.** I am using Android NDK r8.

**P.P.S.** Why you need this ugly assembly? The output assembly listing for:

```
static inline unsigned int L_add(register unsigned int ra, register unsigned int rb)
{
  return (ra > 0xFFFFFFFF - rb) ? 0xFFFFFFFF : ra + rb;
}
```

looks still reasonably efficient and it is much more portable!

Comment: QADD and + don't do the same thing.